# CSS text-overflow: ellipsis wrapping on nested div structure

Tags: html, css, overflow, word-wrap

I have the following 3-level tree of nested divs. The outer one has a max width and I want the ellipsis wrapping on that node, not on the individual child nodes.

I already almost got there, problem is that (depending on the outer width) the inner nodes aren't cut to fit as much text as possible inside the parent node. Instead only as many child nodes are shown as would fit completely, the rest is just blank space. So instead of

`left1~right1 left2~right2…`

I would rather like

`left1~right1 left2~right2 left3~rig…`

To see this effect, you may have to adjust the value of max-width.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
}

.outer {
  background-color: lavender;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner>* {
  display: inline;
}

.inner>:first-child::after {
  content: "~"
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <div>left1</div>
        <div>right1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="inner">
        <div>left2</div>
        <div>right2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="inner">
        <div>left3</div>
        <div>right3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="inner">
        <div>left4</div>
        <div>right4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close to your expected result.

Change `.inner` from `inline-block` to `inline`.

```
.inner {
    display: inline;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
}

.outer {
  background-color: lavender;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.inner {
  display: inline;
}

.inner>* {
  display: inline;
}

.inner>:first-child::after {
  content: "~"
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <div>left1</div>
        <div>right1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="inner">
        <div>left2</div>
        <div>right2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="inner">
        <div>left3</div>
        <div>right3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="inner">
        <div>left4</div>
        <div>right4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The values is corrects...

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
```

As you say, will work only if the content of your element exceeds it's **width**.

Comment: That's not the problem I think, I tested it when it was exceeding width.